# Is a film actor a "thespian"?

Tags: meaning

Can I call a film actor a **thespian**, or does this term exclusively relate to acting on a theater stage?

Comment: I'd do a quick check of Google Books for the name of a film actor (who never acted on stage) with _thespian_, but I don't know of any film actors who never acted on stage.

Comment: I'm not aware of any restriction on the medium for a thespian. But then again, the kinds of people who read articles that use the word thespian _might_ be.

Comment: Apparently Thespian is a proper noun! Who'd've thought?

Comment: “That sounded strange to me, so I called my thespian friend, Eric Oleson (it's okay to call him that because he's openly thespian).” [Newsweek] :-)

Comment: There are plenty of film actors who have never acted on stage in any professional means. A substantial number of American actors, for a start. Probably less common for British actors though.

Comment: Doing a google search for Schwarzenegger and thespian gets hits of it being used ironically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s **predominantly, but not exclusively,** used for stage actors.

Dictionaries — [Merriam Webster](http://www.m-w.com) and the [OED](http://www.oed.com) — define it just as *actor*, without restriction.  Searching well-edited English-language newspapers and browsing through the top hits confirms, though, that it is associated much more with stage than screen: [New York Times](http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch?query=thespian), [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/search?q=thespian), [Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/execute_search.html?text=thespian&ss=smh.com.au).

(Ideally, a COCA or Ngrams search would be better, as @msh210 suggests in comments, but I haven’t managed to think of a query that would work well for this question.)

Comment: The only correct answer I've seen so far. If you used *thespian* in common speech people would probably presume stage actor, unless it was otherwise clear from context.

Comment: *The Grauniad* is well-edited?

Answer (score 4):

Originally it was *Thespian* (from *Thespis* the legendary founder of theatre in Athens), and referred only to study of tragedy and by extension the theatre in general. (My Chambers dictionary has "an actor (*jocular*)", so would presumably be horrified to think it might be extended to a performer in the kinematographs). But words change, and I would think a word for 'someone who performs in the theatre only' would be so little used as to be useless. My own feeling is that *thespian* has a flavour of 'artist', so probably should be used for an actor you respect, rather than those hardworking professionals who appear in daytime soap operas.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd do better not to use it at all, for film actors or for any other kind. It has a jocular tone, and rather a feeble one at that, which you may wish to avoid.

Comment: I can't hear _thespian_ anymore without thinking of [Master Thespian](http://vimeo.com/15476780)

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thespian) is concise:

> **thespian**, *noun*: ACTOR.